# No named parameter with the name interactive

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my flutter application on android studio this error appear, I did flutter clean and many commands but it didn't work.

```
    ../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdown_search-0.6.3/lib/src/selectDialog.dart:193:23: Error: No named parameter with the name 'interactive'.
                      interactive: widget.scrollbarProps?.interactive,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:63:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/saava/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/saava/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 41s
```

Comment: Could you include the output from `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: the output is too big to fit here

Comment: Edit your question to include requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interactive` property of `Scrollbar` was added in Flutter 2.2. If you are using a version older than that, this package (or at least this version of the package) won't work for you. The package's release notes don't make it clear which version you *should* be using, though, but it will probably be some point from 0.5.0 onward since that was the release which supported null safety which corresponds to Flutter 2.0.

Alternatively, you can just update your version of Flutter to 2.2+. (At time of writing, the latest version of Flutter on the stable channel is 2.2.2.)